# Where to add Waypoints "offset" option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Beginner's question.  I am trying to add an offset option to a website using Waypoints, so that nav menu items will only highlight when that section is reached (150px from the top, as it is a 150px tall sticky menu).  I know the offset option is the way to go about this, but I can't find anywhere where it says where to actually add this option.  Please, as basic of a description as possible of how I should add this (is it in the HTML, scripts.js, or waypoints.js)?  It seems like I have added it everywhere to no avail.

Please let me know if you need any more info or to see my code.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Straight from the [Waypoints docs](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs): `$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) { // do stuff }, { offset: 50 });`. Also, I don't know what you mean by 'highlight', but it's possible you could do this with just CSS using the class that Waypoints adds to `sticky` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response-- this is the code that I am adding, but I'm not sure which file/where in which file (index.html, scripts.js, or waypoints.js) I should be adding this?

Comment: And do I need to be adding the class ".thing" to any element in the HTML?

Comment: Replace `thing` with the class of whatever you're setting the waypoint on (the `nav` I guess). I don't know what any of those files you're referring to contain so I can't really answer you. Probably don't put it in `waypoints.js` because I'm assuming that's the (possibly minified) library code you downloaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help-- I have been battling this for a few weeks and have tried seemingly everything, but I know there's one little thing catching me up.  Your answers definitely clear some things up!  I gave this a try, and now the menu items seem to be highlighting/becoming active at the right point, but sometimes are not unfiring.  Would you be able to take a look at [link](http://www.waitingforsunrise.alexagreenfilms.com/index.html) and see if you can tell what I'm doing wrong?  I really appreciate your help.